# C++ POCO THREAD POOL application crashes

Tags: c++, multithreading, threadpool, poco, reactor

I got issue with my server.

Server crashes when i want execute task in ThreadPool.

Here is part of function where thread pool is used :

```
void CSConnection::onReadable(const AutoPtr<ReadableNotification>& pNf)
{
    try
    {
        int n = _socket.receiveBytes(_pBuffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
        if (n > 0)
        {
         //app.logger().information("Packet s " + nb.format(nBytes) + ", group : " + nb.format(_pBuffer[4]) + ", type : " + nb.format(_pBuffer[6]));
            unsigned short packetID;
            packetID = (_pBuffer[4] * 666) + _pBuffer[6];
            switch(packetID)
            {
                case 666:
                    {
                        QuitHandler* qh = new QuitHandler();
                        qh->_con = this;
                        WorkerThreadPool::getInstance().tp->start(*qh);
```

When case 666 is executed, server crashes.
(Only this case use thread pool for tests)

There is WorkerThreadPool class :

```
using Poco::ThreadPool;

class WorkerThreadPool
 {
  private:
        WorkerThreadPool()
        {
            tp = new ThreadPool();
        }
        ~WorkerThreadPool()
        {
            tp->joinAll();
            delete tp;
        }
  public:
        ThreadPool * tp;
        static WorkerThreadPool& getInstance()
        {
          static WorkerThreadPool instance;
          return instance;
        }
 };
```

There QuitHandler class :

```
using Poco::Runnable;


    class QuitHandler : public Runnable
    {
        public:
            QuitHandler(){}
            CSConnection * _con;
            void run();
            virtual ~QuitHandler();
        protected:
        private:
            char * _packet;
    };
```

And run definition :

```
void QuitHandler::run()
{
    Application &app = Application::instance();
    app.logger().information("quith");
    unsigned short len = 9;
    char * reply = new char[len]();
    ///build packet header
    //set len (it's short)
    reply[0] = len & 0xff;
    reply[1] = (len >> 8) & 0xff;
    reply[4] = 3; //group
    reply[6] = 100; //type
    ///body
    //empty
    _con->sendBlocking(reply, len);
    delete [] reply;
}
```

Application crash before log "app.logger().information("quith");".

Thanks.

Comment: If you run your program in a debugger, it will stop at the location of the crash. The debugger will then let you examine both the call stack and variables. At least edit your question to include the callstack (in GDB it's the `bt` command).

Comment: With debugger server crashes on connection with error :
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
At f:\poco-1.4.6p1\Foundation\src\NotificationCenter.cpp:88, without debugger it works normal.

Comment: If a program crashes in the debugger but not otherwise, it can be a sign that you are using an uninitialized pointer. Debuggers may zero out the stack when a function is called, leading local variables to be zero too, and if a local variable is a pointer that will mean it will now be pointing to `NULL`. And if you're using this pointer without checking if it's `NULL` you will most likely get a crash. The reason it doesn't crash when run normally, is because then the pointer will be pointing to a seemingly random location, and you're just lucky that it works.

Comment: Can be there problem in notification pointers like this ? void onReadable(const AutoPtr<ReadableNotification>& pNf)